# HERE Maps: Language for RouteOptions after setLocale in Android N stays system language

Tags: android, here-api

I am using the Here Maps Android SDK Premium, version 3.11.2.82. I have an issue with setting the language to my [RouteOptions](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/routing/RouteOptions.html) object while using the Here maps sdk. When my system language is English and I change the apps language, then from Android N the language in the route results is not updated and the route items show up in English. Here is how I set the RouteOptions when I try to find a route:

```
val routeOptions = RouteOptions()
routeOptions.locale = localeProvider.currentLocale
routeOptions.transportMode = RouteOptions.TransportMode.TRUCK
routeOptions.routeType = RouteOptions.Type.FASTEST
routeOptions.setTruckLength(12.192f)
    .setTruckWidth(2.5908f)
    .setTruckHeight(3.9624f)
    .setTruckLimitedWeight(36.28739f).truckWeightPerAxle = 26.589585f
routePlan.routeOptions = routeOptions
router.calculateRoute(routePlan, RouteListener(destinationSearchResult, routePlan))
```

The locale is definitely different (something like Spanish Locale("es")) and my device is set to English.

I override the language by setting

```
val locale = Locale("es")
Locale.setDefault(locale)
LocaleList.setDefault(LocaleList(locale))
```

I also override these in my base activity:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(updateBaseContextLocale(base));
}

@Override
public void applyOverrideConfiguration(Configuration overrideConfiguration) {
    super.applyOverrideConfiguration(getUserLanguageConfiguration(overrideConfiguration));
}
```

where I set the new configuration with the updated locale to the context. Lastly, I override in my base application the configuration change:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfiguration) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(getUserLanguageConfiguration(newConfiguration));
....
}
```

Where I also update the locale in the new configuration and set it as well to the base context.

The RouteOptions.setLocale(..) works fine in Android M, but from Android N it doesn't. The rest of my application is in the proper language, so is this a bug or am I overseeing something? Are there other ways to set a language/locale to the Here Maps library?

Comment: Thank you for reporting this. We will have a look for the root cause and come back to you later on.

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport any updates on the issue? :)

Comment: What type of object localeProvider that is used to get locale for route settings?

routeOptions.locale = localeProvider.currentLocale

Whether localeProvider.currentLocale property has expected value after changing the locale settings of the application?

Answer (score 1):

Please use our latest HERE Android mobile SDK which is version 3.14. Changing the Locale via the `RouteOptions` should work as described in our documentation:

`Sets the language for route request using a locale.`

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/routing/RouteOptions.html#setLocale-java.util.Locale-

Comment: I will try it, if it doesn't work I'll let you know!